# Avro schema for JSON array having multiple choices in the "choice" field

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am writing an avro schema for my application (writing an app.json file for my application). I am using `{"name": "", "type":"string", "choices":[.... and here there are multiple choices to define....]`.

My question is: In the field "choice"there are multiple choices and they are repetitive just a number is getting change. Can I write the below code in more optimize way. Can I run for loop or any other optimize way.

app.json

```
{"name": "conditions", "type": "string", "choices": ["default", "value1:a", "value1:b" "value2:a", "value2:b", "value3:a","value3:b", "value4:a", "value4:b"........... "value100:a", "value100:b"]}
```

I was thinking of something like below but don't know how to write this:

```
 {"name": "conditions", "type": "string", "choices": ["default", "valueXX:a", "valueXX:b"]}
```

And XX can be define somewhere in the app.json

```
XX:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14...100]
```